# Rounding to a whole number in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, numbers, integer, rounding

I have code like this:

```
Dim minutes As Integer = (55 / 60)
```

I want this to return 0 to me, integer 0 (no decimals), but VB.NET rounds this to 1.

How do I accomplish this?

---

OK for those with the same problem, try dividing with `\` (yeah, it's not escape character in VB.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full decimal division you have to use another operator.

Try:

```
\
```

Answer (score 0):

So round *down*? Use:

```
?Math.Truncate(55/60)
0.0
```

Comment: The guy already answered my question it is simply by dividing with \.However, I'm not sure why, but answer got deleted ?

Comment: was missclicked :) would add some content

Comment: hey SwissGuy thanks for answer, never knew that \ can be used for division in vb.net. You learn something every day.(Though I'm very green in vb.net)

Answer (score 0):

Dim minutes As Integer = Math.Round(55 / 60)

There are overloads that allow rounding to fractional values and specifying which way to round if the value is exactly between two integers.